XAMPP php 8.2.23 Unable to load dynamic library 'curl'
I'm running a local development environment on Windows using XAMPP with multiple PHP versions. I manually switch between the PHP versions by setting the correct paths in httpd-xampp.conf and updating the PATH environment variable as well as the PHPRC variable.
My Setup:
PHP Versions:

php 8.0.30 default php directory that came with XAMPP
PHP 8.1.29 (Working)
PHP 8.2.23 (Not working)
PHP 8.3.11 (Also not tested yet)

PHP Configuration (php.ini):
extension=curl
extension_dir = "C:\xampp\php-8.2.23\ext"

DLL Files:
The file php_curl.dll exists in C:\xampp\php-8.2.23\ext.
The Problem:
When I switch to PHP 8.2.23, I get the following error in my PHP logs:
[05-Sep-2024 03:43:43 UTC] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'curl' (tried: ext\curl (The specified module could not be found), ext\php_curl.dll (The specified module could not be found)) in Unknown on line 0

What I've Tried:

Ensured php_curl.dll Exists: Verified that php_curl.dll is in the correct ext directory for PHP 8.2.23.
Checked libcurl.dll Locations: libcurl.dll is located in C:\xampp\apache\bin. I suspect there might be a version conflict with php_curl.dll.
Configured php.ini Correctly: Ensured that all php.ini files have the correct extension and extension_dir settings.

Question:

Could this be a compatibility issue between libcurl.dll and php_curl.dll for PHP 8.2.23, or might there be another reason why PHP cannot load the curl extension?
Are there other places or configurations I should check to resolve this issue?

Any additional troubleshooting suggestions would be greatly appreciated!
Update
Since the php-8.1.29 folder is working, these are diagnostic steps as suggested by shingo in the comments

commenting out the extension reference - this made the error go away, eliminating the possibility this error is coming from somewhere else
intentionally mislabeling the extension folder I added a "2" to the extension folder thread extension_dir = "C:\xampp\php-8.2.23\ext2"and in response I warnings for curl, fileinfo, mbstring, mysqli, openssl, pdo_mysql and php_ftp which highlighted that all the other modules are loading correctly with the correct entry
running PHP.exe directly - seems to run without issue, so this problem seems to only occur in the context of XAMPP.


What version of XAMPP are you using? These answers may help.

Edit php.ini shown in phpinfo().

@kmoser - XAMPP 3.3.0

@shingo - the php.ini path I see is C:\xampp\php-8.2.23\php.ini, which is the php.ini file I expected

Installation - "In order to enable this module on a Windows environment, libeay32.dll and ssleay32.dll, or, as of OpenSSL 1.1 libcrypto-*.dll and libssl-*.dll, must be present in your PATH. Also libssh2.dll must be present in your PATH. You don't need libcurl.dll from the cURL site."

General advice, if you're wanting to run separate versions of PHP use containerisation. Docker makes this all very easy

If you comment out extension=curl, will this error disappear?

@shingo - interesting idea... but yes, the error does go away

@Phil - very promising suggestion, unfortunately they were already on the path by virtue of the php-8.2.23 folder.
re: Docker - I had a lot of different problems getting that installed, This is a temporary solution to a temp problem then I'm going to use Docker on my Linux partition (setting this machine up to dual boot soon)

Can you try changing extension_dir  to "C:\xampp\php-8.2.23\ext2" and see if the path in the php error will also change to ext2\curl?

@shingo - tried it and the other modules failed like they would in an otherwise normal installation.  Added an update section to note that.

I am confused, you said "this singular module is failing", do you mean only curl is failed? And my question is whether the error message is still tried: ext\curl, or has it become tried: C:\xampp\php-8.2.23\ext2\curl?

@shingo - sorry that was ambiguous, I corrected it.  I tried changing the folder name and all modules failed.  What I meant to say was that this step confirms that only the curl module is failing with the correct path.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

I don't consider this to be the answer, so I won't mark it as the accepted solution, but it is an answer that worked for me that might be helpful to someone.  In my case I needed PHP 8.2 so I backed up my previous version of XAMPP and downloaded a version of XAMPP that includes 8.2.  I installed it and synced up the settings on the following files using a diff tool:

/apache/conf/httpd.conf
/apache/conf/httpd-vhosts.conf
/php/php.ini synced with original settings, but I left any references to the file paths at the original values as I was using the original php folder.
/php/ext/*.dll I didn't overwrite anything, only added missing .dll's
/mysql/data/ copied my previous folder into this folder, overwriting everything (backup first, do this at your own risk, etc... but it worked for me)

Your needs and mileage may vary, but this worked for my installation.  This tells me the problem wasn't related to environment variables or my system in general and seems to be contained to the XAMPP folder.  Hopefully that helps anyone with a similar issue in the future.
